# Passing null or empty string for User ID in Universal Analytics

Tags: javascript, asp.net, universal-analytics

Can we pass null or empty string values for User ID in Universal Analytics tracking? If so, does the analytics treat it as a null/empty value or a valid string? 
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can pass an empty value for User ID. However, this will be treated as a 'new user' each time the individual visits the site as the GA server won't be able to tie sessions together. It would be the same as if you didn't include the User ID in your snippet at all.

The same applies custom dimensions/metrics or any other additional parameters you track.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. Google WILL ignore hits with empty User ID. You should set it to undefined. See solution here: http://dan-russell.com/2014/06/help-i-just-enabled-the-user-id-feature-through-google-tag-manager-and-my-pageviews-dropped/

Answer (score 0):

Sending empty strings in UserID will make the GA Server ignore the hit.